# How to quote from a book which is a collection of stories by various authors?

Tags: quoting

I need to quote a sentence from a book which is a collection of stories of various authors. So usually when quoting a book I would put something like "lalalalala" (John Doe p.101) Now I am not sure if in this case for the authors name I should put down the textbook's author's name or the short story's author name that I am quoting.

Comment: Referencing questions are now off-topic here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard way I was taught to do it is like this, in a footnote or end note:

> ---
>
> 1.) F. Olly, 'Semi-Erotic Dreams From
>   Under the Pear Tree', in: *The
>   Collected Essays of a Reactionary
>   Spirit*, B. Ugger and N. Inny eds.
>   (Yokohama 1951), pp. 23-74: 24.

First the author of the article or story; the part in '...' is the title of the story; the *italicised title* is of the collection it is a part of; then follow the editors of the collection (if any: otherwise leave blank) and the place and year of printing; lastly the pages within the collection that contain the story, and the specific page to which you are referring.

When you quote the same article for the second time, you leave out anything between the name of the article and the final page number. Alternatively you could keep the year too, if you have many articles by the same author and the years are relevant for your readers.